# SQL Server, select query with several combination best practice for index creation

Tags: sql-server

In my log table, there are 10 columns, in that one column is DateTime and others are the integers and one column is boolean. For my advanced search, I need to use the 7 columns for search with DateTime. Which means 7X7 combinations of search with daterange.

I have created the included index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx1 ON MyTable (id1,logtime)
INCLUDE(id2,id3,id4,id5,id6)
```

Like this way, I have created for all columns with logtime and includes the rest of the ids.
Is it a correct way to handle this kind of combination? Please suggest me the best practice.

**Note: This is an advanced search, so the user can choose any combination. My table contains Billions of records
**

Answer (score 0):

The index you have will filter first on id1, then on logtime. The INCLUDE option doesn't add anything to the filtering aspect of the query. This means it's unlikely to assist in filtering for a query. Further, the INCLUDE portion will only help if you're only returning 7 of the 10 columns. If you're returning all 10, then the INCLUDE is a waste of time because the optimizer will still have to go back to the cluster or heap for the rest of the columns.

So, something like this actually hard. There's not one, perfect, right answer. Instead, I can lead you towards a good enough answer. The first thing you must determine is the best leading edge, the first column, for the index. That's because, no matter how many columns you have in the key of the index, only the first one gets a histogram. This is the first thing that helps to determine row counts, and it's row counts the optimizer uses to build out a good query plan. So, you want that first column to be two things, always used in your filtering and selective. I know you said that any combination of the 7 columns could be used, but let's determine which one is always used (surely there is one). Assuming it's not the bit column (which would be horrid as a leading edge), determine how selective it is, the number of unique values it has. It doesn't need to be perfectly unique, just not 10 million of a single value and 1 of a second. A real distribution. That's your leading edge.

Now, which column is the 2nd most used? Add that. 3rd? Add that. 4th? And so on. Adding all seven is unlikely to be useful, but may be. INCLUDE probably isn't needed.

You may find that you have two or three common patterns for the majority of the queries. In this case, you may be better served by having two or three indexes, with different leading edges and column order. Don't be afraid to add indexes BUT at the same time, don't just add them wildly. Every index carries with it overhead as well as performance assistance, so you have to balance cost & benefit.

Test everything. Watch the execution plans.